# A proposition on exact sequence of inverse limit (Lang, Algebra, p. 165)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

[image: proof]

I am trying to understand this proof.

My only question is that what are the vertical maps here?

Comment: I do not see any vertical maps...which maps do you mean?

Comment: That is $ \lim_{N}C_n \to \lim_{M}C_n$ where $N\geq M$ and the similar types.

Comment: Note that $\lim_NC_n\subset\prod_{n=1}^NC_n$. This product has projection maps
$$\prod_{n=1}^NC_n\ \longrightarrow\ \prod_{n=1}^MC_n,$$
for all $M\leq N$, and their restrictions to $\lim_NC_n$ yield the maps $\lim_NC_n\ \longrightarrow\ \lim_MC_n$.